# How to check occurrence of value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var arr = ['09:30:00', '09:45:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '10:30:00', '10:45:00', '11:00:00', '11:15:00'];

var $elem = $("<table>", {
  'class': 'table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table',
  'border': '1'
});
var $tbody = $("<tbody>", {
  'class': 'overview_table_td'
}).appendTo($elem);
$.each(arr, function(i) {
  $tbodyTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($tbody);
  if (i % 4 == 0) {
    $tbodyTH = $("<th>", {
      'scope': 'row',
      'html': arr[i].slice(0, -6),
      'rowspan': '4'
    }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
  }
  $tbodyTH = $("<th>", {
    'scope': 'row',
    'html': arr[i].slice(3, 5)
  }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
});

$(".overview").html($elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview">
</div>
```

I am getting unexpected output when I do `i % 4 == 0` but I have can I achieve from array that 09 occurs how many times.

If there any solution for it?

**Expected Result**

Look if in array there is a 09:30:00, 09:45:00. so after slice this value i m getting 2 times 09. so i want to use that counter in `i % 2 == 0`, and you can see further after slice i can get 10, 4 times so if condition will be `i % 4 == 0`

So i want to run if condition 2 time when it is 09 and 4 time when it is 10.

Hope you get my expected Result.

[image]

Need Help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "unexpected output" a little more?

Comment: @JHolub click on "Run code snippet", you'll see.
OP you are assuming the dates are grouped by 4 which is incorrect, but I couldn't think of a simple answer right now.

Comment: Thanks @NathanP. !      Well i represents the index, right? So i % 4 == 0 means every 4th time this condition will be true. The output looks expected as far as the code goes. I think you wanna go a different road, right? You wanna have the hours on the left and the minutes (if existing) on the right, right?

Comment: @JHolub I just edit my question hope now you will get my question

Comment: @JHolub in the expected output, we have two rows for 9, four for 10 and 2 for 11, so running this condition every 4th time is incorrect.

Comment: Yes i know that, this is a issue. i want to run 2 time when it is 09 and 4 time when it is 10.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Liam Please don't put tags in question titles? it Means? what i do mistake in title?

Comment: you started your question [jQuery -](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44653585/revisions) I removed it as this shouldn't be done, [as per the guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). BTW your question is very unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try saving the previous hour and adding a new cell to the first column only after it changes. In the first iteration `old` and `oldTH` are undefined so the `hr != old` consition is met. After each new cell you should also update the previous cell's `rowspan` property. This update has to be done even after the `.each()` finishes.

See the code below:

```js
var arr = ['09:30:00', '09:45:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '10:30:00', '10:45:00', '11:00:00', '11:15:00'];

var $elem = $("<table>", {
  'class': 'table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table',
  'border': '1'
});
var $tbody = $("<tbody>", {
  'class': 'overview_table_td'
}).appendTo($elem);

var counter = 0;
var old, oldTH;

$.each(arr, function(i) {
  $tbodyTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($tbody);
  
  var hr = arr[i].slice(0, -6);
  
  if(hr != old){
   if(counter > 1){
     oldTH.attr("rowspan", counter);
    }
    old = hr;
    counter = 0;
   $tbodyTH = $("<th>", {
      'scope': 'row',
      'html': hr,
    }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
    oldTH = $tbodyTH;
  }
  
  ++counter;
  
  $tbodyTH = $("<th>", {
    'scope': 'row',
    'html': arr[i].slice(3, 5)
  }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
});
if(counter > 1){
  oldTH.attr("rowspan", counter);
}

$(".overview").html($elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview">
</div>
```

Comment: Was working on a solution just like that as well but the rowspawn was tricky. Nice you solved it in such an elegant way :)

Answer (score 1):

Was a bit slow in posting and see there's already an answer in the meantime, but posting it anyway if only for not throwing it away right away ;)

```js
var arr = ['09:30:00', '09:45:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '10:30:00', '10:45:00', '11:00:00', '11:15:00'];

var $elem = $("<table>", {
  'class': 'table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table',
  'border': '1'
});
var $tbody = $("<tbody>", {
  'class': 'overview_table_td'
}).appendTo($elem);

var $thHour;

$.each(arr, function(i,val) {
  $tbodyTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($tbody);
  var parts = val.split(':'),
    hour = parts[0];
  if ($thHour && $thHour.hour === hour)
    $thHour.rows++;
    else {
      if($thHour)$thHour.end();
      $thHour = $("<th>", {
        'scope': 'row',
        'html': hour,
      }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
      $thHour.hour = hour;
      $thHour.rows = 1;
      $thHour.end = function(){this.attr('rowspan', this.rows);}
  }
  $tbodyTH = $("<th>", {
    'scope': 'row',
    'html': parts[1]
  }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
});

$thHour.end();

$(".overview").html($elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview">
</div>
```